# MySQL structure changes without table locking on RDS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, percona

I have an AWS RDS MySQL database of around 2.5TB; I need to do some structure changes, and would like to perform them without table locking. I'm aware of the following options:

1. Percona Toolkit
2. Replication
3. MySQL Online

Which option is best for my needs, and easier to perform on RDS? AFAIK both are possible, but both require adaptations of RDS which don't come easy. If I'm missing a 4th option, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

1. [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-online-schema-change.html) is probably your easiest solution for RDS. Run this from an EC2 instance, in a screen session.
2. Replication in RDS is extremely difficult to set up because you don't have SUPER in RDS but this is the safe method if you don't want to use pt-osc.
3. I'm not sure what "MySQL Online" is but possibly you are referring to the new online DDL features of InnoDB. Depending on the size of the individual table and also depending on what you want to ALTER, this could work too. Be sure to read up on [what is supported](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) for ALGORITHM=INPLACE. If the tables in question are only a couple hundred MB, just use regular ALTER TABLE and take the couple minutes of downtime for the smaller ones.

Comment: What do you mean by "screen session" ?